# Lattice of continuous functions

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $\mathcal C
[0
,
1]$ be the set of continuous functions from $[0
,
1]$ to the reals. Define
$\leq$
on
$\mathcal C
[0
,
1]$ by
$f
\leq
g \iff
f
(
a
)
\leq
g
(
a
)\; \forall
a
\in
[0
,
1]
$.
Show that
$\leq$
is a partial order which
makes
$\mathcal C
[0
,
1]$ into a lattice

Comment: Being a partial ordered set doesn't imply it is a lattice. Do you know what you have to do to prove it is a partial order?

Comment: You need to think of two operations both of which take two functions and return a function. Hint: a linearly ordered set is a lattice because of the max and min functions.

Comment: @GitGud Yeah I know that I need to show that any two element in the set should have an infimum and a supremum under the same ordering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show that a partially ordered set $\langle \mathbb{P},\preceq\rangle$ is a lattice, you need to show that any two elements of $\mathbb{P}$ have both a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound.

In the case of $\langle \mathcal{C}[0,1],\leq\rangle$, this means that for $f$ and $g$, you must find continuous functions $f\vee g$ and $f\wedge g$ with the following properties:

1. $f\leq f\vee g$
2. $g\leq f\vee g$
3. $\forall h\in \mathcal{C}[0,1] \big(\big((f\leq h) \& (g\leq h)\big) \to (f\vee g)\leq h \big)$
4. $f\geq f\wedge g$
5. $g\geq f\wedge g$
6. $\forall h\in \mathcal{C}[0,1] \big(\big((f\geq h) \& (g\geq h)\big) \to (f\wedge g)\geq h \big)$

In fact, this is pretty straightforward.  The obvious choices for $f\vee g$ and $f\wedge g$ work, and the proofs of 1-6 are more or less immediate.  The only tricky thing is to show that  $f\vee g$ and $f\wedge g$ are actually continuous.

---

In fact, if you already know that $[0,1]$ is a lattice, and that the function space $$[0,1]^{[0,1]}=\prod_{i\in [0,1]}[0,1]$$ is *ipso facto* also a lattice, then you can take a shortcut.  The lattice $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ is the set of *all* functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ (not just continuous ones), and the $\vee$ and $\wedge$ functions there are defined pointwise (since it's a product).

Then, to prove that $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ is a sublattice of $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$, all you need to do is show that $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ is closed under the operations $\wedge$ and $\vee$ inherited from $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$.  In other words, show that the (pointwise) meet and join of continuous functions are also continuous.

This is similar to proving that $H$ is a group by showing that $H$ is a subset of a group $G$, and that $H$ is closed under the group operations.

Comment: What is the obvious choice for (f join g) and (f meet g). I tried to use f join g is f+g but I cant seem to prove that its the least upper bound. i.e I am stuck in proving the 3. point on your list.

Comment: I guess I should be more circumspect in my use of words like "obvious." Think about $\mathbb{R}$. The least upper bound of 3 and 4 isn't 7, it's 4. See if you can extend this reasoning to $\mathcal{C}[0,1] $.

Comment: I understood the first part of the proof. But I couldn't follow the second method. In fact I am unfamiliar with the notation itself. Can you give me some reference where I can read on it.

Comment: If you're taking a lattice theory course (lucky you!), there should be a section on the product of lattices in your textbook.  If you haven't got to it yet, you will soon.   The exponential notation is a way to describe a set of functions.  If $A$ and $B$ are sets, then $A^{B}$ is the set of functions with domain $B$ and codomain $A$.  (The notation comes from combinatorics; the number of functions from a set of size $k$ to a set of size $n$ is $n^{k}$.)  Finally, there's an obvious way to describe functions in terms of points in products. For now, observe that $A^{\{0,1\}}\simeq A\times A$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1.reflexivity:$f\leq f$ it's obvious

2.antisymmetry $f(a)\leq g(a)$ and $g(a)\leq f(a)$ for all $a\in [0, 1]$ then $f=g$

3.transitivity $f(a)\leq g(a)$ and $g(a)\leq h(a)$ then $f(a)\leq g(a)$

It's lattice because each $f\in C[0,1]$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ is compact so has sup and inf on this interval.